# How to implement FM Transmitter in android?

Tags: android, fm-radio

I want to know how to implement FM Transmitter in android app. I want my android phone generate a radio frequency. So that I can play music on my phone and transmit it over radio frequency for a near by radio receiver (may be in a car) can amplify to larger audience. Just like TuneAudio on Nokia C7.

Comment: A similar question was answered quite a while ago, [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098353/implement-java-fm-radio/11098430#11098430)

Comment: Simple grammar needs to be improved here. Read the FAQ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would - **need an FM Transmitter** - that is, the *appropriate hardware* for generating frequencies in the desired range.

It is a good thing [portable FM Transmitters](https://www.google.com/?q=portable+FM+transmitter) can be bought from many electronic retailers. They usually plug into the 2.5mm jack and have a battery for several hours of transmission; there are Android/Phone-specific models as well.

The Nokia C7 *already has* the appropriate hardware built in. The standard "Android" does not.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

Somebody over at XDA mentioned a similar thing

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1092719

It sounds really complicated, and potentially only available to certain roms, meaning it's probably not something easily achievable on android at the moment.

Anyway good luck, I'd love to see this happening.

Comment: hmmmm thanks @timusus
I am looking for that but yet din get any success.However found i link [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300129/android-fm-radio-transmitting) but is of no use :(